# What is the most commonly used metric in $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

I am reading Conway's *Functions of One Complex Variable*, and many times it makes reference to a function from $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ being continuous. I would like to rigorously prove such assertions, so I have to know which metric he is referring to. I haven't taken topology, so I'm not sure what the most natural or nice metric would be. The one I've come up with is $d[(z_1, w_1), (z_2, w_2)] = |z_1-z_2| + |w_1 - w_2|$.

Is there a "natural" metric that is most often used on $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}?$

Comment: To define "continuous" you only need a topology, not a metric.  There may not be a "natural" metric on $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C$, but there is a natural topology.  Alternatively, even for metric spaces, there is a natural notion of "continuous" for a function of two variables; this does not require defining a metric on $\mathbb C \times \mathbb C$

Comment: Basically $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{R}^4$. I would say that the natural metric is the Euclidean.

Comment: The one you have come up with is called the **taxicab metric**. On the other hand, the metric often used is $\sqrt{|z_1 - z_2|^2 + |w_1 - w_2|^2}$. However, for proving convergence, continuity, etc, you are free to choose either of these metrics. It is an exercise in topology that both metrics induce the natural product topology on $\Bbb{C} \times \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Ah thank you all for the comments

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a *continuous map* between metric spaces is usually introduced via the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition. In a more general form your question is this: If we are given metric spaces $(X_1,d_1), (X_2,d_2)$, how do we define a metric $\Delta$ on $X_1 \times X_2$?

There is no standard definition of $d$, but a *standard requirement*. Here it is:

For any metric space $(Y,d)$, a map $f : (Y,d) \to (X_1 \times X_2,\Delta)$ is continuous if and only if the two maps $p_i \circ f : (Y,d) \to (X_i,d_i)$, where $p_i : X_1 \times X_2 \to X_i, p_i(x_1,x_2)= x_i,$ are continuous. If you take a topology course, this requirement will become very clear. At the moment accept it as it is.

You will see that there are many solutions for $\Delta$. In your answer you gave one, and in the comment by ZeroXLR you have another one. However, all metrics with the desired property turn out to be *equivalent*, and this means that it is not really important which you choose. In *topological terms* the essential point is that the product of topological spaces can be endowed with a unique *standard topology* with reasonable properties.